# Is there No Point to use instanceof with primitive types array?

Tags: java, class, object, instanceof, primitive-types

This is somehow the same as asking: **Is there anything that subclass / superclass the primitive types?**

*(Because `((Object) (new String[6])) instanceof Object[]` is true, as `String extends Object`.)*

For instance, of `int[]`, is it **ONLY** `((Object) (new int[3])) instanceof int[]` is true, among anything in Java?

If so,

```
((Object) (new int[3])) instanceof int[]
```

is identical to

```
((Object) (new int[3])).getClass() == int[].class
```

and i would prefer the latter one, as it should be faster, as it doesn't have to check every type/class inheritances.

Comment: I hope you're just curious... and that you're **not** writing code that looks anything like this.

Comment: In fact, in my codes, the `object` comes from the parameter. I was just using casting to test these cases.

Comment: If you can modify the code, maybe you can make your method accept a `List<T>` as a parameter instead of an Object.  Then you won't have to worry about casting.  That said, we know nothing about what you're trying to do...

Comment: i know what i am doing. Just that method does not. The method is intended to accept anything and determine the type of the parameter.

Answer (score 5):

It is really difficult to understand what you are asking, but I think you are asking whether using `getClass()` is better than using `instanceof` for array types.

From the perspective of readability, `instanceof` is better:

```
   Object obj = new int[3];

   if (obj instanceof int[]) {
       int[] array = (int[]) obj;
   }

   if (foo.getClass() == int[].class) {
       int[] array = (int[]) obj;
   }
```

Clearly, the first form is more readable.

From the performance perspective, I cannot see why the two versions *could* not be identical.  In the `instanceof` case, the `int[]` type has no subtypes, and therefore it can be compiled to something that is equivalent to *or potentially even faster than* the `getClass()` version.

The only way to be sure which is actually faster is to write a decent microbenchmark and run it on the platforms that you are interested in.  And note that you are liable to get different performance results for different versions of Java

However, I strongly suspect that the performance difference will be too small to make any difference to your application.  Unless you *already* have concrete profiling results that point to this as a bottleneck ... you are probably wasting your time.

---

> This is somehow the same as asking: Is there anything that subclass / superclass the primitive types?

No.  It is not equivalent to asking that at all.  Java array types are not primitive types.  They are reference types.

It is however related to the question of whether there is a subtype relationship between array types.  Or to be more accurate, it boils down to whether you can cast from one array type to a different array type.

And the answer to that it depends on the base type; see [JLS 5.5.1. Reference Type Casting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1).  If the base types are (different) primitive types, then the answer is no.  If the base types are reference types, then if you can cast from one base type (`BC1`) to the other (`BC2`) then the cast involving the array types (`BC1[]` to `BC2[]`) is also legal.

So this means that `instanceof` and `getClass()` tests will give the same answer for array-of-primitive types, but not for all array types.

---

In fact, it was arguably a mistake in the original Java language design to allow *any* casting between different array types.  This leads to anomalies such as this:

```
    Object[] a = new String[1];
    a[0] = new Object();  // throws ArrayStoreException !!!
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Performance is not my prime concern, as i know the different should be minor. As i know `String[] instanceof Object[]` is true. And generally, `SubClass[] instanceof SuperClass[]` is true. The most i am focusing on the correctness, in which `something instanceof int[]` is identically equals to `something.getClass() == int[].class` in all cases. As you said "the int[] type has no subtypes~, so can i assume they are identical in all cases?

Answer (score 1):

(A instanceof B) returns true when A "isa" B, or when you could use A where a B is expected.
Any comparison of class objects or class names using == will compare for identity.  If you need to know that A and B are EXACTLY the same type, you could use A.getClass() == B.getClass().
The primitive types do not inherit from Object, but arrays do.  For example, you can say

```
if(new int[2] instanceof Object)
```

but not

```
if(new int[2] instanceof Object[])
```

The latter will not compile.

In Object Oriented Programming, you generally care about equivalence rather than exact types.  I would argue that you almost always want to test for suitability (with instanceof) rather than for identity (with ==).

Note that your cast to Object is not needed.

```
if(new String[2] instanceof Object[])
    System.out.println("true");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. +1 for raising the point "primitive types do not inherit from Object, but arrays do". So do you mean there is absolutely nothing subclass & superclass primitive types? If yes, `something instanceof int[]` is identical to `something.getClass() == int[].class` in all cases, isn't it?

Comment: I can't find a way to extend an array type, so I guess I agree - the instanceof and class comparison should always be the same.  I would choose the expression that most clearly expresses what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not a pure OO programming language,because there are primitive data types.

**Q:Is there anything that subclass / superclass the primitive types?**

**A: No,primitive has no subclass of superclass, it's just primitive type.**

Array in Java is object type, whether it's content is object type of primitive type, so the following
statement is true:

```
 System.out.println("Is int[] instance of Object:"+(intArray instanceof Object));       
 System.out.println("The type of int[] is:"+(intArray instanceof int[]));
 System.out.println("Is the class of intArray equal to int[]:"+  
           (intArray.getClass()==int[].class));
```

**Q:i would prefer the latter one, as it should be faster, as it doesn't have to check every type/class inheritances.**

**A:No,there is no evidence for that. Even if it's true, it's not a problem in Java, for efficiency is not always our consideration**